# Is it possible to locate functions from executable at runtime on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

I'm injecting code into a function in windows in order to create hooks. I have this thread within the process, which successfully creates hooks to functions exported by DLLs.

I'm planning to extend this functionality to include some functions or methods within the executable itself. All I need now is a pointer to the function in order to create hook to it using bytecode level code injection.

Now is it possible to locate functions at runtime within a process's memory, which are loaded from the executable file itself?

Comment: Define what you mean by "locate functions" please. How do you propose to identify them? What meta data do you have available for the executable file? PDB file? MAP file?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I only have the .exe file, which loads some DLLs.

Comment: Also by locating functions I mean finding pointer to them at runtime.

Comment: Unless the functions in question are exported from the module (in which case locating them is trivial) there is no way to even identify a function. Those functions do not have names. You have to know the address to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When source code is compiled into executable code, things like function and variable names are lost. Unless you have metadata like debug information database, .pdb/.dbg or a map file, .map, then you are not able to find functions in general.

If the function is exported by the module, then you can find its address with `GetProcAddress`.